# How do I replace files with a push to an existing app on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, git, mongodb, shell, heroku

I am new to Heroku, and have been developing locally, comfortably..

I have read through all the getting started tutorials for node.js & mongoDB.

I am working to get a grasp on the command line tools for heroku, and seem to have an issue with this:

I have my codeset in a folder..then..

```
cd /ParentFolder/ChildFolder/FolderWithCodeFiles
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "init"
```

Which sets up git (that's installed on my mac) for the folder that's cd?..then..

```
$ heroku create
$ git push heroku master
```

But how can I push my code before getting the MONGODB_URI from one of the mongodb addons?

Is there a way to push the code from my local folder after creation, addon installation, and app.js updating?

Comment: could you explain your problem?
is MONGODB_URI a env variable?

Comment: The process is the same. "Pushing" is simply a 'git push' operation to a remote repo--in this case, the one hosted by Heroku for your app. You can continue to execute 'git push' commands to update your Heroku app as many times as you wish after the app is created.

Comment: @prattsj that makes sense.. but could you explain the semantics of init and "init"..? What do they refer to?

Comment: @Ali i think so.. it's what the mongodb addons provide for connecting to their servers.. but it's added after the heroku app is created, which is after I upload my local files, which is before I change the app.js to include the new variable?!